# How do I get Github Pages to generate a list of my blog posts?

Tags: github-pages

I want to include a list of links to my blog posts on the home page of my site.

I understand the code to do this is

```
 {% for post in site.posts %}   
    <h3><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
    <p><small><strong>{{ post.date | date: "%B %e, %Y" }}</strong> . {{ post.category }} . <a href="http://mypage.github.com{{ post.url }}#disqus_thread"></a></small></p>          
{% endfor %}
```

but I wonder where to put this code?

I tried adding it to default.html inside a new section but I received a "Page Build Fails" email

Comment: Studying https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the code inside a section seemed to be my mistake.

Putting it below the header works

```
  <header>
      <h1>{{ site.title | default: site.github.repository_name }}</h1>
      <h2>{{ site.description | default: site.github.project_tagline }}</h2>
    </header>
{% for post in site.posts %}   
    <h3><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
    <p><small><strong>{{ post.date | date: "%B %e, %Y" }}</strong> . {{ post.category }} . <a href="http://myname.github.com{{ post.url }}#disqus_thread"></a></small></p>            
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you , I didn't realize that I could executable code inside markdown. I will give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you want the list of posts to appear everywhere in the site or just the home page. In the case of the home page, you should add it to your `index.html` file. In the case of everywhere, adding it to the `default.html` would be a better idea.

Here's how it would look like in your `index.html` file:

```
---
layout: default
---

{% for post in site.posts %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

In this case, everything other than the YAML front matter will become the `{{ content }}` in your `_layouts/default.html`.

If you do use something like your `_layouts/default.html`, then include it anywhere inside the `body` of your HTML.

Comment: Thanks, however I am using index.md